# Specify Sonarqube parent module

Tags: sonarqube

I have set up a multi-module SonarQube project using the stand-alone sonar-runner.  When I run analysis from the parent directory, everything shows up in SonarQube as I would expect, grouped under my parent module.  However, if I go into one of my sub-modules and run analysis, I end up with a new project created in SonarQube that stands on its own, outside of the parent module.  Is there a way I can run analysis just on the sub-module and have it publish the results in the right area, still grouped under my parent module?

My parent module's sonar-project.properties looks something like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.my.project
sonar.projectName=My Project (Parent Module)
sonar.projectVersion=0.1

sonar.modules=data,business
```

And in my sub-module

```
sonar.projectKey=com.my.project.data
sonar.projectName=My Project Data
sonar.projectVersion=0.1

sonar.src=src
```

I have also tried to define a projectKey in my sub-module like this

```
sonar.projectKey=com.my.project:com.my.project.data
```

But that throws an error in SonarQube stating that the project is already defined in SonarQube but as a module of project "com.my.project".

I am using SonarQube version 5.2 and SonarQube Runner version 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to build only a module of multi-module project in SonarQube.
Either you analyse the module with a different key, but it will create a new project as you've seen, either you analyse the whole project.

Why do you need to analyse only on module ? What is your use case ?

Comment: We have a set of microservices that I wanted to group under one project.  I was hoping to run a big initial analysis on everything once, and then add in a build step for our CI server to analyze individual modules when they changed.  Instead, I ended up adjusting filters so that each module is it's own project, but I group them all together in dashboards to give a better view.

Comment: Such feature already exists with the commercial Views plugin : http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/